# How to declare an Array of Realm Results in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm, swift4

Is it possible to make an array of realm results in swift 4? , I've tried this one `var RealmArray = [[Results<Object1>?](),[Results<Object2>?](),[Results<Object3>?](),[Results<Object4>?]()] as [Any]` but this looks like not good to me , I want to use and display the data inside of every object to the tableView but I don't know how to properly use their indices. Someone knows how to declare an `Array of Realm Results`?

**Or Do you know how to merge the 4 `Realm Results`?**

This is for my SearchBar(For those who want to know for what I will use this for).

**my declaration**

```
var main_tcb_filteredArray:Results<TrialCourtBranches>?
var main_ibp_filteredArray:Results<IBPChapters>?
var main_pao_filteredArray:Results<Pao>?
var main_lac_filteredArray:Results<LegalAidClinics>?
var RealmArray = [[Results<TrialCourtBranches>?](),[Results<IBPChapters>?](),[Results<Pao>?](),[Results<LegalAidClinics>?]()] as [Any]
```

**Filtering for my searchbar**

```
   let tcb = realm.objects(TrialCourtBranches.self)
   let tcb_predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(branch_name CONTAINS[c] %@)",searchText.lowercased())
    main_tcb_filteredArray = tcb.filter(tcb_predicate)

   let ibp_predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(chapter CONTAINS[c] %@)",searchText.lowercased())
   let ibp = realm.objects(IBPChapters.self)
   main_ibp_filteredArray = ibp.filter(ibp_predicate)

   let pao_predicate = NSPredicate(format: "office_name CONTAINS[c] %@",data.lowercased())
   let pao = realm.objects(Pao.self)
   main_pao_filteredArray = pao.filter(pao_predicate)

   let lac_predicate = NSPredicate(format: "school CONTAINS[c] %@",data.lowercased())
   let lac = realm.objects(LegalAidClinics.self)
   main_lac_filteredArray = lac.filter(lac_predicate)

   main_combined_filteredArray = [main_tcb_filteredArray!,main_ibp_filteredArray!,main_pao_filteredArray!,main_lac_filteredArray!]

   self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: this works for me `var RealmArray = [[Results<String>](),[Results<Int>]()] as [[Any]]`

Comment: Results of Object sir , not just common data type @Reinier Melian

Comment: Have you tried to insert the datas to the tableView? @ReinierMelian

Comment: I can provide an example of how it works I think

Comment: okay , thank you @ReinierMelian

Comment: by the way why you don't use three arrays?

Comment: the problem here is that you can't add in an array objects of different types like `Results<TrialCourtBranches>`, `Results<IBPChapters>`, `Results<Pao>`

Comment: i will use that `RealmArray` for my searchbar , the data inside of those Results is the filtered data from realm database @ReinierMelian

Comment: @ReinierMelian please have a look into my edited post , I added my filtering and my other declaration

Comment: @ReinierMelian No solution??

Comment: the problem is when you need to fetch those values from Realm and add in your single [Result] this is not allowed by Swift because the type difference, I think you need a different approach

Comment: @ReinierMelian you have any suggestions??